# my htaccess will not remove php and redirect the non existing pages to another page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have my .htaccess working perfectly, I want it to remove the .php and to redirect all non-existing pages to pub-temp page.. 
but, after I uploaded it on host, they have their code for forcing https and www, so my commands are not working anymore, any help in that ?

this is the complete htaccss:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force to WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]  

#MY CODE HERE
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pub-temp.php
```

Comment: There is no conflict between those rules, they _should_ work fine together. Though the rules certainly could be improved I see no reason why they should not work as describe. There must be some other effect.

Comment: btw if I delete the host commands, it works ... what to do now !?